# How to loop through a particular tag and display it row after row?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am a beginner in XSLT. I am trying to create an AFP document using Apache FOP.
I have an input XML like this:

```
<letter>
 <data>
   <product>
     <a>test</a>
     <b>test1</b>
     <product>
      <charge>
        <one-time-charge>
         <amount>30</amount>
         <info>MNO</info>
        </one-time-charge>
      </charge>
         <product>
          <charge>
           <one-time-charge>
            <amount>10</amount>
            <info>XYZ</info>
           </one-time-charge>
          </charge>
         </product>
         <product>
          <charge>
           <one-time-charge>
            <amount>20</amount>
            <info>ABC</info>
           </one-time-charge>
          </charge>
         </product>
     </product>
    </product>
    </data>
   </letter>
```

As u can see, there are 3 levels of "product" tag.
The "product" tag levels can sometimes be 2 as well.

the expected output is as below:

```
MNO                                       30
XYZ                                       10
ABC                                       20
```

How do i loop through the "info" tag and "amount" tag irrespective of the  level?

Update:

After using descendant axis :

I am able to get the values out of this code, but it does not add new row for each info

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/product/product"> 
 <fo:table-row> 
  <fo:table-cell> 
   <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal"> 
 <xsl:value-of select="descendant::one-time-charge/info"/> 
 </fo:block> 
 </fo:table-cell> 
<fo:table-cell> 
   <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt" font-weight="normal"> 
 <xsl:value-of select="descendant::one-time-charge/amount"/> 
 </fo:block> 
 </fo:table-cell>
 </fo:table-row> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output is as follows:

```
MNO XYZ ABC                          301020
```

Required:

```
MNO                               30
XYZ                               10
ABC                               20
```

Comment: There are actually two ways you can do this. One is through recursion, and the other by using the descendant axis to select all product elements regardless of their level.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - edit your question and add it there. Also add the exact output you expect to get at the end of the transformation (as XSL-FO code), before rendering.

Comment: sure, sorry. Edited it now

Comment: Still no code for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the descendant axis as suggested, you should be doing something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="//product/charge/one-time-charge"> 
            <row>
                <cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="info"/>
                </cell> 
                <cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="amount"/>
                </cell> 
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```